# Is it possible to create a data breakpoint in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The data breakpoints in Visual Studio is very a very useful debugging tool and I need something like that for my current iPad project (pointers and memory acting strange).

Is it possible to create data breakpoints in Xcode?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the documentation for the Watchpoint in Xcode :

> To monitor changes to the value of
>   variables or data items, you can set
>   watchpoints. A watchpoint pauses
>   execution of the program whenever the
>   value of the watched item changes. You
>   can set a watchpoint on a variable
>   only when execution of the program is
>   halted. To set a watchpoint on a
>   variable:
>
> With execution of the program paused
>   at a breakpoint, select the variable
>   in the Variable list in the Debugger
>   window. See “Debugging in the
>   Debugger” to learn more about the
>   Variable list. Choose one of the
>   following: Run > Variables View >
>   Watch Variable Watch Variable from the
>   variable list shortcut menu Xcode
>   displays a magnifying glass next to
>   the variable to indicate that the
>   variable is being watched, as shown in
>   Figure 7-5. Figure 7-5  Watched
>   variable in the Variable list
>
> When the value of the variable
>   changes, Xcode pauses execution of the
>   program and displays a dialog showing
>   the location of the program counter
>   and the new value of the variable. If
>   execution of the program moves beyond
>   the scope of the current variable,
>   Xcode deletes the watchpoint and
>   pauses execution of the program.
>
> Important: Watching local variables,
>   located on the stack, can cause your
>   program to crash if system calls are
>   made in the current function.

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to watch instance variables? They doesn't show up in the Variable Watch.

Comment: Yes they do, you have to expand the object variable (self for the current object) to access to its instance variables.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Visual Studio but I guess you're looking for watchpoints. Search for "watchpoint" in the [Xcode Debugging Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html).

Comment: This link is now broken. Maybe it has been replaced by [this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html)?

Comment: Thanks @ReinhardMänner, I updated the link. Feel free to just suggest an edit to the answer next time!

Comment: @w-m OK, will do!