# triggering a breakpoint on variable change

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there any way to set a breakpoint in XCode so it breaks every time a variable is changed, and show's me where it's happened?

For example an int.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378019/is-it-possible-to-create-a-data-breakpoint-in-xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way its call key-Value observing. You can read about it here: [Introduction to Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i)

Comment: This isn't the same as setting a breakpoint. It'll give you a method in which a breakpoint could be set, but it won't work for simple ivars that don't already have KVC compliant setters. Watchpoints are much better.

Comment: KVO could call a function that you could break at. But yes there is an issue if its not KVO Compliance.