# Use "data breakpoint" on Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, breakpoints

On Xcode, is it possible to set a breakpoint on an attribute value ? (stop if attr==nil for example) I know it is set to nil, but I can't find where and by whom.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a data breakpoint in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378019/is-it-possible-to-create-a-data-breakpoint-in-xcode)

Comment: "I know it is set to nil" Do you really? How do you "know" that? You have not shown any code so I'm not convinced. Show us this "attribute". Show how you know that it changes to nil. I'm betting that it was never set to nil - rather, it came into existence as nil and was never set to anything else.

Comment: I know that it is set to nil because it is used as a parameter for a calculus of a variable. This variable is nil when my attribute is nil. The problem is that the bug is random, sometimes my attribute is set to nil, sometimes not, so I think I could have a memory problem.

Answer (score 2):

Open Xcode.

Open the 'Breakpoint Navigator' (cmd+7)

In lower left, click the + button

Select 'Add Symbolic Breakpoint..'

In 'Symbol' add:  `[YourObject setYourAttribute:]`

In 'Condition' add: `yourAttribute == nil`

This will get called anytime `yourAttribute` on `YourObject` is set to nil.  You can then look at the trace to see what sequence of events led to that call.  I'm pretty sure that's what you're asking.

Comment: Does it work even if I am sure that it is not a setter that modifies the value of the attribute ?

Comment: @Kaki - Is there a specific reason you're not using the setter?

Comment: I 've investigated and set breakpoint everywhere my attribute should be set, but the program never stops. I think maybe the attribute is overwritten somewhere, but I can't find where.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a setter to access the variable in question, you'll have to drop down to using LLDB (Xcode's debugger) directly to do what you want.

Set a normal breakpoint in a context where the variable you're interested in is in scope, and before it has been written by your mystery writer. Then, access the debugger pane, and enter the following command:

```
watchpoint set variable -w write <variable-name>
```

where `<variable-name>` is the name of the variable you'd like to watch – perhaps `attr` in this case. This will set a hardware watchpoint which will trigger when your variable is changed.

If you want to explore LLDB a little more, try help commands in the debugger. For example, you could type:

```
help watchpoint set variable
```

to see the help entry for the command I've recommended.

**EDIT:** Apparently you can also [set such watchpoints from the Xcode GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378019/is-it-possible-to-create-a-data-breakpoint-in-xcode?rq=1). Who knew?

Answer (score 0):

1) Set breakpoint in the method
2) Right click on the breakpoint, and select "Edit Breakpoint"
[image]

3) Add Condition `attr == nil`
[image]

4) Click somewhere in Xcode.

You are ready to go, breakpoint will stop whenever `attr == nil`